# Best way to check a lot of check boxes in a checkboard game

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have in a game a lot of check boxes, that needs a set of rules. There is a rule, which is a one cross check box only should be there in one row of the whole matrix. I pictured the problem as a 2D array, and just check each row/column. Is there a faster way or a better approach, because there will be a lot of IFs, ELSEs..

[image: Sample]

Comment: There is no faster way than to visit each cell of each row. About `if` statements... if you write a loop you should get away with one or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll depend a lot on how you're representing your matrix... If I understood your problem, the easiest way is to simply make a loop, and for each row, count the number of *checks checked*. So:

> for each row:
>
> if col1 = is checked, check++
>
> if col2 = is checked, check++
>
> if col3 = is checked, check++
>
> if check > 1 tell the user that there is an error.
>
> end for

If you change your matrix to store a 0 value for unchecked and 1 for checked, you could test it like:

> for each row:
>
> if col1 + col2 + col3 > 1 tell the user that there is an error
>
> end for

Comment: the matrix is represented as a 2D of check boxes and each checkbox can be checked or not checked.

Comment: Ok, so you'll have to verify each check box, like the answer I gave... this "checking" could be faster if you tested, when the user checked the box, if another check was made in the same row.